# NSJSONSerialization : unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization

Normally following code working properly but sometimes I think, JSON returns nil and encounter fatal error. How can I handle it if data is nil.

I encounter EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on following line :

```
let profileJsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray
```

Appreciate your help.

```
do {
        let profileJsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray

        if let parseJSONArray = profileJsonArray {                
            self.myProfileinfo = parseJSONArray

                    let name: String? = self.myProfileinfo[0].valueForKey("fullname") as? String
                    let messsage: String? = self.myProfileinfo[0].valueForKey("message") as? String
                    let infourl: String! = self.myProfileinfo[0].valueForKey("thumb") as? String
                    let prourl: String! = self.myProfileinfo[0].valueForKey("prothumb") as? String
                    let email: String? = self.myProfileinfo[0].valueForKey("email") as? String ...
```

Comment: Are you trying to read from network response? if so, check `error` before using `data`

Comment: Yes, it is from a PHP file

Comment: Likely data = nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading from network response, you should check whether there's an error first.

`NSSession` for example:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    if error {
        // Deal with error, e.g.
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        do {
            // Use data or response
            let profileJsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSArray
            // ....
        }
        catch {
            // Deal with error
        }
    }
})
task.resume();
```